# How Do i use Just The EXE for VB.Net

Tags: exe

I want to use Just the EXE But when I Got To Drag to desktop and use it, it wont work, But when i keep it with all its files it works I tried rebuilding but all I got was the .dll. What I want To do is to be able to keep it on my desktop and give it to my friends to teach them about code with out them getting my Code.

Comment: There's should be an exe file inside your bin folder. The dll files are libraries that are required by your application. If you wish to distribute only single exe file, you can use tools such as [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge). Or, use `PublishSingleFile=true` if you are using .NET Core.

Comment: create shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

You can build an installation package which you share with others. These installation packages do not include your source code.